# Navbar not showing up in Rails Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am putting together a basic website from One Month Rails and can't seem to figure out how to get the navigation bar to show at the top. I have spent a few hours and would like to go to the community. Here is the code from the _header.html.erb (using bootstrap sass)

```
<div class="navbar navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
             <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <%= link_to 'Home',  root_path %>
                        </li>
                        <li>    
                            <%= link_to 'About',  about_path %>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li><%= link_to 'Login',  '#' %></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code from the application.html.erb tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
          <title>One Month Rails</title>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
          <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= tag :meta, name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" %>
        </head>
        <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some HTML errors in `application.html.erb`. But most modern browsers will fix those errors for you when loading the page. Here's a better version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>One Month Rails</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= tag :meta, name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
            <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You should also make sure your `_header.html.erb` is in `app/views/layouts/`.

Finally, don't forget to add bootstrap's css file to `app/assets/stylesheets/`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The issue was I had mistakenly had my header file in app/views/pages instead of app/views/layouts/